# How to display list of high scores on a game in two tables?

Tags: php, html, html-table

I want to display a list of top ten players on the high scores list, in a table from database i want it in a format that one half of the div element it should display  top 5 players and other half of player ranking 6-10.Currently my code is as given below any one help me out...

```
echo('<table id="pattern-style-a" summary="Meeting Results">');
echo('<thead><tr><th scope="col">Profile</th><th scope="col">Score</th></tr>
    </thead><tbody>');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$count++;
?>    
<tr><td><?=image($row['user_id']);?><br /><a href="<?=$row['link']?>" target="_blank"><?=$row['name']?></a></td><td><?=$row['result']?></td></tr>
<?  
} 
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try structuring the table like this:

```
<table>
<tr><td>

    <table [1-5]>


</td><td>

    <table [6-10]>

</td></tr>
</table>
```